# OpenMP slower reduction

Tags: openmp

There are two versions of openmp codes with reduction and without.

// with reduction

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
  for (i=1;i<= num_steps; i++){
      x = (i-0.5)*step;
      sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
  }
```

// without reduction

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{
  int id = omp_get_thread_num();
  int numthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  double x;

  double partial_sum = 0;

  for (i=id;i< num_steps; i+=numthreads){
      x = (i+0.5)*step;
      partial_sum += + 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
  }
#pragma omp critical
      sum += partial_sum;
}
```

I run the codes using 8 cores, the total time double for the reduction version.  What's the reason?  Thanks.

Comment: How are you measuring the time? How large is num_steps? It's possible the first one is slower because it's first. If you're not doing a warmup phase, it may be paying for OpenMP startup costs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually parallelize the loop as well as the reduction you can do it like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
{
  int id = omp_get_thread_num();
  int numthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  int start = id*num_steps/numthreads;
  int finish = (id+1)*num_steps/numthreads;
  double x;
  double partial_sum = 0;

  for (i=start; i<finish ; i++){
      x = (i+0.5)*step;
      partial_sum += + 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
  }
  #pragma omp atomic
  sum += partial_sum;
}
```

However, I don't recommend this.  Reductions don't have to be done with atomic and you should just let OpenMP parallelize the loop.  The first case is the best solution (but make sure you declare x private).

**Edit:** According to  Hristo once you make x private these two methods are nearlly the same in speed.  I want to explain why using critical in your second method instead of atomic or allowing OpenMP to do the reduction has hardly any effect on the performance in this case.

There are two ways I can think of doing a reduction:

- Sum the partial sums linearly using atomic or critical
- Sum the partial sums using a tree.  I.e. if you have 8 cores this gives you eight partial sums you reduce this to 4 partial sums then 2 partial sums then 1.

The first cast has linear convergence in the number of cores.  The second case goes as the log of the number of cores.  So one my be temped to think the second case is always better.  However, for only eight cores the reduction is entirely dominated by taking the partial sums.  Adding eight numbers with atomic/critical vs. reducing the tree in 3 steps will be negligable.

What if you have e.g. 1024 cores?  Then the tree can be reduced in only 10 steps and the linear sum takes 1024 steps.  But the constant term can be much larger for the second case and doing the partial sum of a large array e.g. with 1 million elements probably still dominates the reduction.

**So I suspect that using atomic or even critical for a reduction has a negligable effect on the reduction time in general.**

Comment: No iterations are skipped. The second code fragment is exactly equivalent to `parallel for` with `schedule(static,1)` being applied to `for (i = 0; i < num_steps; i++) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar reduction in OpenMP is usually quite fast. The observed behaviour in your case is due to two things made wrong in two different ways.

In your first code you did not make `x` private. Therefore it is shared among the threads and besides getting incorrect results, the execution suffers from the data sharing. Whenever one thread writes to `x`, the core that it executes on sends a message to all other cores and makes them invalidate their copies of that cache line. When any of them writes to `x` later, the whole cache line has to be reloaded and then the cache lines in all other cores get invalidated. And so forth. This slows things down significantly.

In your second code you have used the OpenMP `critical` construct. This is a relatively heavy-weight in comparison with the atomic adds, usually used to implement the reduction at the end. Atomic adds on x86 are performed using the `LOCK` instruction prefix and everything gets implemented in the hardware. On the other side, critical sections are implemented using mutexes and require several instructions and often busy waiting loops. This is far less efficient than the atomic adds.

In the end, your first code is slowed down due to bad data sharing condition. Your second code is slowed down due to the use of incorrect synchronisation primitive. It just happens that on your particular system the latter effect is less severe than the former and hence your second example runs faster.

Comment: Although your points about `x` not being private and using critical (instead of at least atmoic) are good points (which I made as well), I think the main reason the second code is faster is because it's skipping several iterations which of course makes it faster.  It's not even doing the same thing.

Comment: Absolutely not true. Both codes do the same total number of iterations. And when `x` is made private, the only small difference (4,6.10^-14 %) in the results from both variants comes from the non-associativity of the floating-point addition.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  Too bad, I started with the problem being x being shared instead of private (the correct answer) and then made a mistake.

Comment: Interesting that using a chunk size of one makes no difference.  I guess that is because this is just doing a calculation and not accessing memory.

Comment: I added an edit explaining why I think using critical instead of atomic or just letting OpenMP do the reduction has no realy effect on the time.